# How can I implement field level decorators in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pydantic

One of the things I like about Java/Spring is the support for field level decorators for MongoDB. Can something similar to what's below be achieved in Python (preferably using Pydantic)?

```
class Customer(BaseModel):
  id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
  first_name: str = Field(alias='firstName')
  last_name: str = Field(alias='lastName')
  @Transient
  full_name: Optional[str] = Field(alias='fullName')
```

By marking a field as **@Transient**, it would not be persisted to MongoDB *but would be included* when the object is encoded to JSON in a RESTful API.

Perhaps there are better ways to achieve this but it seems like a good use case for decorators.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the role of pydantic in what you said about "it would not be persisted to MongoDB"? And about "[it] would be included when the object is encoded to JSON", are you referring to the `.json()` method of `BaseModel`?

Comment: In the example, the field called "full_name" would not be written / stored into MongoDB when a call to insert_one (Pymongo) is made.  If the field is populated and an instance of Customer is returned as the result of a REST call, the object would be encoded back to the REST client as:

{
  "id": "12345",
  "firstName": "Bill",
  "lastName": "Gates",
  "fullName": "Bill Gates"
}

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You mention another library involved: "Pymongo", and I guess that the answer about persistence would be specific to "Pymongo" and not necessarily to pydantic. Is there another library involved in the transformation from a pydantic model to JSON?